# q.js: difference between resolve() and fulfill()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, q

I'm still unclear on the difference between calling a resolver's resolve() vs fulfill()? I see both the functions and the terms "resolve a promise" and "fulfill a promise" batted around a lot.

When should I be using each?

Comment: I don't see a `fulfill` method in the `q` documentation. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: see also [What is the correct terminology for javascript promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572)

Comment: every man and his dog keep using resolved and fulfilled interchangeably. To my way of thinking, resolved means no longer pending. e.g. the promise was resolved, with success.. or the promise was resolved, with error; or the promise was resolved, with another promise...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `resolve`. `deferredPromise.resolve(nextPromise)` means that anything waiting for `deferredPromise` will now wait for `nextPromise`. If `nextPromise` is not a promise at all, it gets turned into a fulfilled promise which goes on to inform anything waiting for it that the value has become available.

The `fulfill` method is a bad idea that will be deprecated and eventually go away entirely. `fulfill` is semantically equivalent to `resolve` in all useful cases.  It’s only reason to exist is that `deferredPromise.fulfill(value)` is easier for humans to interpret than `deferredPromise.resolve(value)`, since `resolve` is overloaded to handle both `nextPromise` and `finalValue`.

The problem with `fulfill` existing at all is that `deferredPromise.fulfill(rejectedPromise)` is semantically paradoxical.

Comment: …unless we would allow nested promises - semantically pure :-)

Comment: @Bergi, there has been much discussion of this, but `resolve` does not need to change. There is talk of moving coercion into `then` (and others), and using `flatMap` to unwrap strictly monadic promises.

Answer (score 15):

In general, **resolve** means to EITHER succeed or fail. That is what triggers the invocation of the `then` actions. It can happen exactly once for any given promise.

**fulfill** means to "resolve" *successfully*. That will trigger the success callbacks in the `then` actions. The counterpart of "fulfill" for failure is **reject**.

From a different perspective, you can categorize the status of any promise at a particular point in time as "unresolved" (sometimes also called **pending**) or "resolved", and "resolved" has the sub-statuses of "fulfilled" and "rejected". A promise in "fulfilled" status has a **value**, and a promise in "rejected" status has a **reason**.

The particular methods in each API used to represent these notions differ. And unfortunately, there are many blog posts and documents out there which confuse these terms, in particular using "fullfill" when they mean "resolve" or vice versa.

## Q

I do not know Q very well, but it appears that its `resolve` method actually *fulfills* the promise (emphasis added):

> Calling resolve with a non-promise value causes promise to be
>   **fulfilled** with that value.

The twist, however, is that you can also call `deferred.resolve` with a promise, in which case the first promise more or less assumes the state of the passed-in promise. For instance, if the passed-in promise is in "pending" state, the promise adopts the pending state of the passed promise. That implies the slightly odd semantics that a method named `resolve` actually does not resolve the promise.

Comment: I like your explanation. You are right, it's really confusing that different API implementation choose different meaning for the `resolve` and `fulfill`.