# What is the correct terminology for javascript promises

Tags: javascript, promise, terminology

I'm getting confused with the different terminology thrown around. From my understanding, a promise can be:

- fulfilled
- rejected
- pending
- settled
- resolved
- defer

Does resolved mean settled? Or does it mean it’s fulfilled? And what the heck is defer?

Comment: Unfortunately, this terminology is not used consistently. In particular, way too many people use "resolved" to mean "fulfilled". You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280375/q-js-difference-between-resolve-and-fulfill/18295163#18295163

Comment: A perfect opportunity for applying the word "renege" was wasted when selecting these terms.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Terminology can be hard.
Let's take from the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#promise-states) and the [respective ES6 section](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-promise-objects) that there are *3 states*:

- **pending** - the promise has not taken a value yet, its outcome is still uncertain.
- **fulfilled** - the promise successfully got a *result value* "assigned"
- **rejected** - the promise is given a *reason* why no result could be acquired, typically an error.

The term **settled** is a hyperonym for fulfilled and rejected, meaning either - the opposite of pending.

The dynamic verbs **fulfill** and **reject** describe changing the state from pending into either the fulfilled or rejected. These transitions are called **fulfillment** or **rejection** of the promise.

Those were easy. Now, **resolve** is a different beast. It sometimes is used synonymous to "fulfill", but it would better be understood as settling the promise's fate to either fulfilled or rejected. The **resolution** (seldom: settlement) of a promise means that it leaves the pending state. But not even that is accurate - the problem is the recursive nature of the *Promise Resolution Procedure*:

- resolving a promise with a "plain" value means fulfilling it
- resolving a promise with a promise (or thenable) means adopting its state:

  - resolving with a fulfilled promise is a fulfillment
  - resolving with a rejected promise is a rejection
  - resolving with a pending promise means waiting for its resolution

Yes, if a promise is resolved it might not even be known whether it's going to be fulfilled or rejected. But it means the fate is ***no longer undetermined***, as it's bound to the promise that we resolved with - notice that you can resolve a promise only once, it cannot be resolved to a different value (by calling `resolve`/`reject` again).

Ignoring this special case, a **resolved** promise usually means a settled promise.

Or, to cite the [ECMAScript 6 Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-promise-objects):

> *A promise is* resolved *if it is settled or if it has been “locked in” to match the state of another promise. Attempting to resolve or reject a resolved promise has no effect. A promise is* unresolved *if it is not resolved. An unresolved promise is always in the pending state. A resolved promise may be pending, fulfilled or rejected.*

[image: state diagram with transitions]

---

> and what the heck is defer?

**Deferring** a result means that you return an (asynchronous) promise for the result, and not the result directly (synchronously). And also return a deferred rejection [instead of throwing synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887856/1048572).

Notice that "**defer**" is also used in some libraries ([Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdefer)) as the method name to construct a `Deferred` object - see [this answer on *The differences between Deferred, Promise and Future*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858041/1048572) for a good explanation.
Oh, and never trust variable names: `defer` might as well be an abbreviated "deferredObject".

Comment: typo: hyperonym → hypernym

Comment: A+ for that visual

Comment: Also known as "preaching in the wilderness".

Comment: The visual is very helpful, but would be more so if it were made clear that "pending" includes the part of "resolved" that is not included in "settled". As it is, it gives the impression that "pending" and "resolved" are mutually exclusive, contrary to the quote from the ECMA spec.

Comment: Great answer. The key is to understand the difference between "resolve" and "settle". As per the spec: "A promise is resolved if it is settled **or if it has been “locked in” to match the state of another promise**". Note that the other promise might still be pending (not settled). I like to think as "resolved" = "settled+" (pun on Promise/A+).

Comment: What might be confusing is that in most cases "resolve" only means means "**fulfill** or match state of another promise". E.g. for a non-thenable value, `Promise.resolve(..)` or `new Promise((resolve, _) => {resolve(..)})` only ever create a fulfilled promise, but never a rejected one. However, for the unusual case of a non-promise thenable, it could reject or fulfill (i.e. settle). Therefore "settle or match state of another promise" is actually correct.

Comment: hi @Bergi +1 , that means that **all** promises are *resolved*, once they are *resolved*, they will take a *rejected* or *fulfilled* status, right?

Comment: That is, they all go through the "state" resolved @Bergi

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer No. You can resolve a promise with another never-resolving promise, then it won't settle (reject or fulfill) either.

Comment: Excellent @Bergi +1, I didn't know that case. For example, if I use `Promise.resolve('a value')` the promise is resolved, but there it can already take the rejected or fulfilled state, i.e. nothing prevents that it can still be rejected, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer If you resolve a promise with a string, it's immediately fulfilled with that string. It won't ever be rejected. It's only that when you resolve a promise with another promise (or thenable) that its eventual fate might not be known.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, `Promise.resolve()` had me confused. One last question, so, `Promise.reject()` with a value other than a promise will always be rejected , right?

Comment: i.e., it applies the same as Promise.resolve() but for rejected state @Bergi

Comment: Actually no, `Promise.reject()` *always* returns a rejected promise, not matter what value you pass in. Even a promise - you can reject a promise with a promise. You shouldn't ever do that, it's weird, but it's possible.

Comment: hi @Bergi +1. "*resolving a promise with a "plain" value means fulfilling it*" - That case is when it resolves to something other than a promise object, right?

Comment: Yes, "plain" means "non-thenable"/"non-promise" there.

Comment: "*Ignoring this special case, a resolved promise usually means a settled promise.*" - Thanks @Bergi, so this quote refers to when the promise resolved to something other than non-thenable/non-promise, right?

Comment: @Coder23 Yes. A resolved promise literally is just one whose `resolve`r function has been called.

Answer (score 13):

The three promise states are listed in [section 2.1 of the Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#promise-states).

From the specification:

[image]

So here are each of the terms you asked about:

**Pending** is the initial promise state.  The operation represented by the promise has not yet been filfilled or rejected.

**Fulfilled** is another of the three promise states.  It means that the promise has been resolved and now has its resolved value.  The operation represented by the promise has been completed successfully.

**Rejected** is another of the three promise states.  It means that the promise has been rejected and now has its rejected reason.  The operation represented by the promise failed to obtain a value and thus has a reason for failing to do so (typically an error code or error object, but it can be anything).

**Settled** is a term that means the promise is either fulfilled or rejected (e.g. it's not pending any more), but it is not a separate state just a descriptive term to indicate it is no longer pending.

**Resolved** is a term that is often used to mean the same as `fulfilled`, but the two are not exactly the same.  A promise can be resolved with a value which leads to fulfillment or it can be resolved with a rejected promise (which leads to rejection of this promise) or it can be resolved with a pending promise (which means it will now be waiting on the eventual state of some other promise).

It's hard to say exactly what you mean by **defer**.  Promises are often classified as `deferred` objects in that they are an object that represents an action and result that is deferred to the future (it will occur in the future).  In some promises implementations, there are actually two types of objects, a `deferred` object and a `promise` object.  The deferred object is a superset of the promise object.  Both can observe when the action is resolved or rejected with `.then()` handlers.  But, only the `deferred` object can actually change the state to `resolved` or `rejected`.

In jQuery, you can create a deferred object with `$.Deferred()`.  In other implementations such as ES6 promises, you just have promise objects with a constructor callback that has `reject` and `resolve` functions.  The world is presumably moving toward what ES6 will have.

jQuery example that uses a `deferred` object:

```
function delay(t) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        defer.resolve();
    }, t);
    return defer.promise()
 }

 delay(200).then(function() {
     // run my delayed function now
     doMyThing();
 });
```

ES6 promise example:

```
 function delay(t) {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             resolve();
         }, t);
     });
 }

 delay(200).then(function() {
     // run my delayed function now
     doMyThing();
 });
```

Comment: They don't like it when you quote the spec. /s

Comment: @MillieSmith - yeah as much as I like and use MDN as a useful resource, it seems to have the promise states wrong this time so I thought it wise to go right to the spec.

Comment: @jfriend00: See my answer to clear up the difference between resolving and fulfilling. Your description isn't inaccurate enough for a downvote, though :-)

Comment: @Bergi - OK, I cleaned up some of my description of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Domenic Denicola's "[States and Fates](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/docs/states-and-fates.md)" is a good, pithy summary.

States:

- a promise is *fulfilled* if `promise.then(f)` will call f "as soon as possible"
- a promise is *rejected* if `promise.then(undefined, r)` will call r "as soon as possible"
- a promise is *pending* if it is neither fulfilled nor rejected.

Fates:

- a promise is *resolved* if trying to resolve or reject it has no effect, i.e. the promise has been "locked in" to either follow another promise, or has been fulfilled or rejected
- a  promise is *unresolved* if it is not resolved, i.e. if trying to resolve or reject it will have an impact on the promise.

Follow the link for details 'relating states and fates'.