# Convert promise to bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I found an existing library that uses promises, however it doesn't use bluebird. The library functions don't come with all the extra features bluebird does like `.map()` or `.tap()`. How do I convert a "normal" or "non-bluebird" promise to a bluebird one, with all the extra features bluebird offers?

I tried wrapping the existing promise in `Promise.promisify` and `Promise.resolve` and neither seemed to work.

Comment: Updated & found the correct answer, this wasn't particularly straightforward because I've always had a bluebird promise at the top of my promise chain.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use [`Promise.resolve`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promiseresolvedynamic-value---promise) - it will take any thenable, like a promise from some other implementation, and assimilate it into a Bluebird promise.

Keep in mind that [the term "resolve"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572) can be misleading, it does not mean the same as "fulfill" but can also follow another promise and settle to its result.

Comment: @danfromisrael `Promise.resolve` will also take rejected promises and assimilate them just the same.

Comment: Example: 
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.resolve(nonBluebirdPromise).reflect()

Reflect is a bluebird function only, and would not have been available otherwise

Comment: @danfromisrael "resolve" can be misleading. It doesn't mean "success". "resolving" a Promise means waiting until it either succeeds or fails. So Promise.resolve just settles/resolves to the value status of the passed promise, be it a success or an error.

Comment: @d512 please don't copy CodeBling's comment into my answer, especially not without attribution

Comment: @Bergi Why not? It improved the answer (it helped me anyway) and his wording seemed just fine so I left it the way it was.

Comment: Because, uh, [plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism)? Upvoting his comments should have been enough.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to convert the promise to a bluebird promise resolve nothing and return the `customPromise` then you'll have access to all of bluebirds custom methods in the chain.

```
Promise.resolve().then(function(){
  return customPromise()
})
```

Or

```
Promise.resolve(customPromise())
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve(customPromise())` should be enough, there is no need for an extra `.then`.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny a `Promise.try` would also work if you need to guard against synchronous exceptions

Answer (score 3):

Use Bluebird's `Promise.method`!

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const fn = async function() { return 'tapped!' };

bluebirdFn = Promise.method(fn);

bluebirdFn().tap(console.log) // tapped!
fn().tap(console.log) // error
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `to-bluebird`:**

```js
const toBluebird = require("to-bluebird");

const es6Promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve("Hello World!")); // Regular native promise.
const bluebirdPromise = toBluebird(es6Promise); // Bluebird promise.
```

**Native alternative:**

In ECMAScript:

```
import {resolve as toBluebird} from "bluebird"
```

In CommonJS:

```
const {resolve: toBluebird} = require("bluebird")
```

Usage:

```
const regularPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("Hello World!") // Resolve with "Hello World!"
})

const bluebirdPromise = toBluebird(regularPromise) // Convert to Bluebird promise

bluebirdPromise.then(val => console.log(val)) // Will log "Hello World!"
```