# Promises/A+ compliant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Could someone give me a **definite** answer to the following:

```
Are pure Javascript promises (not jQuery ones) Promises/A+ compliant?
```

The same question and for Angular JS promises, please.

Thank you

Comment: `pure Javascript promises` - which browser/environment?

Comment: Just check whether they are on [the list](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations).

Comment: @Bergi - I don't see that that list includes any browser implementations.  Also doesn't include Angular.  So, I'm not sure how that list helps answer the question.

Comment: @jfriend00: You're right, browser implementations should not be on that list but ES6 should be - all ES6-conformant promises are Promises/A+ compliant as well. Admittedly, *current* browser implementations [might not be ES6-compliant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34965087/1048572). I guess Angular is not on that list because it uses its own digest cycle instead of asynchronous scheduling, but otherwise it's fine.

Comment: jfriend00 is right, the list is not the best way to confirm this. Instead, just [run the **test suite**](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests) on the implementation in question to get a definitive answer.