# Make await return thenable, or infinite recursion in awaiting awaitable

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

Trying to come up with API, mixing in promise functionality like:

```
class Awaitable {
  constructor () {
    this.promise = Promise.resolve()
  }
  then (fn) {
    // awaited result must be _this_ instance
    return this.promise.then(() => fn(this))
  }
}

let smth = await (new Awaitable())
console.log(smth)
```

This code creates recursion. 
The main point is to have `smth` to be the newly created thenable instance.

Stubbing `then` with `null` makes awaited result incomplete.

I wonder if that's possible at all, seems like there's some conceptual hurdle, I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: No, you cannot resolve a promise with itself.

Comment: It seems like not only with itself, but with any thenable in general. Is there any workaround?

Comment: What is your actual main point? What are you trying to do here? Why do you need an `Awaitable` class? You don't *want* to create the recursion, right?

Comment: Imagine jQuery to be awaitable and return set when all effects are done `let $target = await $(target).fadeIn(100)`

Comment: The jQuery wrapper in fact *is* awaitable, it just takes calling an extra method: [`.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/). But the resulting promise fulfills with `undefined` afaik, not with the jQuery wrapper itself.

Comment: That's nice workaround, but hoped to find a proof the initial or similar API is not possible. I believe that could be useful pattern for organizing APIs.

Comment: The promise returned by `jQueryObj.promise()` resolves with `jQueryObj`. See [first example here](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Comment: Yes, TY, the point is not jQuery, but the pattern for organizing such APIs - not 100% that jQuery way is the standard.

Comment: Hard to work out what you are trying to achieve that's not already provided by promises with or without async/await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The correct solution

[Symbol.thenable](https://snek.dev/proposal-symbol-thenable/) proposal.

```js
import { parse as parseStack } from 'stacktrace-parser' 

class Awaitable {
  constructor () {
    this.promise = Promise.resolve()
  },

  [Symbol.thenable]: false,

  then(fn) {
    this.promise.then(() => fn(this))
    return this
  }
}

let smth = await (new Awaitable())
console.log(smth.then) // function
```

#### Fragile [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) solution

Detecting if `thenable` instance is called by `await` is possible by parsing callstack. Here's solution based on [stacktrace-parser](https://ghub.io/stacktrace-parser) package:

```js
import { parse as parseStack } from 'stacktrace-parser' 

class Awaitable {
  constructor () {
    this.promise = Promise.resolve()
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Awaitable.prototype, 'then', {
  get() {
    let stack = parseStack((new Error).stack)
    
    // naive criteria: if stacktrace is leq 3, that's async recursion, bail out
    // works in webkit, FF/nodejs needs better heuristic
    if (stack.length <= 3) return null
    
    return (fn) => {
      this.promise.then(() => {
        fn(this)
      })
      return this
    }
  }
})

let smth = await (new Awaitable())
console.log(smth.then) // function
```

The heuristic must be enhanced for FF/nodejs, to solidify - that'd require sort of static analysis wizardy.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense for a promise (or any thenable) to fulfill with itself. If you already had the object, you wouldn't need to wait for it.

[Resolving a promise does automatically unwrap thenables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34964819/1048572), which would create infinite recursion in your case where it would resolve with itself, and you [can (unfortunately) not avoid that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572). So just don't attempt to do it. Fulfill your promise with nothing (`undefined`) instead.

```
class Awaitable {
  constructor () {
    this.promise = Promise.resolve(undefined); // simplified
  }
  then(onfulfill, onreject) {
    return this.promise.then(onfulfill, onreject);
  }
  // other methods
}

const smth = new Awaitable();
await smth; // works just fine now
console.log(smth);
```

Comment: Yes, but what is achieved that's not already available from `const smth = Promise.resolve(undefined);` in the usual way? Maybe if the OP could explain "pattern for organizing such APIs" ....

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I would expect the thing to wrap a more complicated promise, and to have more methods than just `then`. Otherwise yes, one would just use the plain promise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 by pattern I mean `let s = await (new Something()).asyncA().asyncB()` - that is very handy for organizing queues of tasks per instance. That can be anything - from database connectors to backend APIs. In particular, I'm implementing that in https://github.com/spectjs/spect.

I think I'll try dynamic `then` method - if there's something scheduled, the instance is thenable, otherwise not - await doesn't cause recursion that way.

I'll try to come up with an answer.

Comment: @dy_, at a tangent to what you are asking here, you might be interested in the [Fantasy Land Specification](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land).