# Returning another aysnc function in resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function call like so:

```
await someFunction(foo);
```

With `someFunction` defined like:

```
const someFunction = foo => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (foo) {
      return resolve(someOtherPromise());
    }
    reject();
  }
}
```

Is this valid code? I have tested it and it seems ok.

Is it correct that `await someFunction()` will transform to `await someOtherPromise()` if `foo` is `true` i.e. will it continue waiting for `someOtherPromise` to resolve?

Comment: Promises are automatically flattened, you never have to deal with "a promise within a promise" - a `Promise<Promise<T>>` is automatically merged to become `Promise<T>`.

Comment: @VLAZ is it correct to return `resolve(someOtherPromise());` or is just `return someOtherPromise()` sufficient?

Comment: Returning from the promise executor *doesn't resolve it*. You have to call the `resolve` parameter. In fact, returning from the promise is pretty much irrelevant - the value isn't used anywhere (in this case) and the only data that the promise will produce is what you pass into `resolve()`.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Forget the `return`. Do I need to call `resolve(someOtherPromise())` or can I just call `someOtherPromise()`?

Comment: Do you want the value from the other promise or not? If you do `p1 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(makeAnotherPromise()))` (let's assume `makeAnotherPromise` will eventually resolve to `42`) then what you get after `await p1` resolves is `42`. If you do `p2 = new Promise(resolve => { makeAnotherPromise(); resolve() })` then `p2` will resolve to `undefined` (you don't pass anything to `resolve`) also `makeAnotherPromise()` might still not be finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is valid code and works [by resolving with a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34964819/1048572), but smells like the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). I would instead recommend to write

```
function someFunction(foo) {
  if (foo)
    return someOtherPromise();
  else
    return Promise.reject();
}
```

or

```
async function someFunction(foo) {
  if (foo)
    return someOtherPromise();
  else
    throw;
}
```

(and better throw a  `new Error` with a message, not `undefined`)

Answer (score 0):

I've written some test code to see if it's true:

```js
const someFunction = foo => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (foo) {
      return resolve(someOtherPromise(2000));
    }
    reject();
  });
}

const someOtherPromise = async(ms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("i'm about to resolve in someOtherPromise");
        resolve();
    }, ms));
}


const run = async () => {
    await someFunction('foo');
    console.log('finished waiting for someFunction');
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written 3 function to test it out.

```js
c = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('c');
        resolve();
    }, 1000);
});
b = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('b');
        resolve(c());
    }, 1000);
});

a = async () => {
    console.log('a before');
    await b();
    console.log('a after');
};

a();
```

As we can see, the output order is `a before`, `b`, `c` then `a after`. So `await` had waited for `b` and continued waiting for `c`.