# Is it possible to get data of two files like so using then function using bluebird promise?

Tags: bluebird

Is it possible to get data of two files like so using then function using bluebird promise?

```
fs.readFileAsync('directory/file1.txt')
        .then(function(fileData1){
            return fs.readFileAsync('directory/file2.txt');
        })
        .then(function(fileData2){
            return console.log(fileData1+fileData2);
        })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852343/convert-promise-to-bluebird

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the first `fs.readFileAsync('directory/file1.txt')` call in `Bluebird.resolve` to convert to Bluebird promises, but you won't have the result of the first file in the handler of your second 'then' function.

In your case you can do them both in parallel using `Bluebird.all`.

```
Bluebird.all([
  fs.readFileAsync('directory/file1.txt')
, fs.readFileAsync('directory/file2.txt')
])
  .spread(function(file1, file2) {
    console.log(file1 + file2);
  })
```

If you use `Bluebird.all` remember that it takes an Array.