# Bluebird and es6 promises in typescript

Tags: typescript, promise, bluebird, typescript-typings

I started a new project where I'd like to use TypeScript instead of pure Javascript. I am struggling with the use of Bluebird in conjunction with third party libraries.

**See the following example:**

```
  import * as Promise from 'bluebird'

  private requestPlayerProfile(playerTag:string):Promise<IPlayerProfile> {
    const requestOptions = Object.create(this.options)    
    return this.limiter.schedule(request, requestOptions)
  }
```

The problem: `limiter` is an instance of a third party library and limiter.schedule returns a native promise apparently, while I am using the Bluebird promises in the rest of my application. How would I properly handle such cases?

> [ts] Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type
>   'Bluebird'.   Types of property 'then' are
>   incompatible.

Comment: It depends on the type of Promise the library you're using returns. If it returns a vanilla Promise, you could either map manually from one to the other or simply use the native Promises instead of bluebirds.

Comment: What is a vanilla Promise? I think it returns a native ES6 promise and when I use the native Promise I would literally need to use native Promises everywhere or? So all routes / functions which call the requestPlayerProfile function need to work with Bluebird too. Doesn't really convince me to use Bluebird if I really need to mix native and bluebird Promises all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Filipe is interpreting the error message correctly.

- Whatever is the type of object returned by `this.limiter.schedule(...)`, that type is incompatible with `bluebird.Promise<IPlayerProfile>`.
- Nobody can reliably assume that `limiter.schedule(...)` returns a "vanila", i.e. a native, `Promise<IPlayerProfile>` object. You can easily figure it out by going to the source code where `schedule(...)` is defined. In my Visual Studio code I use <kbd>F12</kbd> to get there. Notice the precise return type of the object there.
- Depending on what exactly is returned, you have two major options:

  1. Use that promise type everywhere in your code instead of relying on `bluebird`'s promises altogether; or
  2. [Convert that promise type to a `bluebird` one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852343/convert-promise-to-bluebird). I have not tried myself, but the following should work: `return Promise.resolve(this.limiter.schedule(request, requestOptions))` (see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html).

I hope it helps.