# Regarding Promises/A+ Specification, is a promise ever allowed to never resolve or reject?

Tags: javascript, promise

In the Promises/A+ standard, I am wondering if a promise needs to resolve or reject *eventually*. By this I mean a promise X with the property that under no condition whatsoever will X get resolved or rejected.

[Promises/A+](http://thanpol.as/javascript/promises-a-performance-hits-you-should-be-aware-of/) states

> 1. When pending, a promise:
>
>    i. may transition to either the fulfilled or rejected state.

It is the **may** part that is the ambigious too me. I do not know whether to read it as saying "It *may* transition but may not" or that it will transition eventually and it may transition to fulfilled or rejected.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I think you can keep it pending as long as you want, and that there is no requirement that says you *have*  to resolve it. The question is why wouldn't you? At least in your code, if the user leaves before it's resolve/rejected, it's a different matter.

Comment: If you don't resolve or reject your promise, then you're a `liar` and should be using `FalsePromise()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the spec does not mandate this. There is no restriction on how long a promise should take to settle. And that includes an infinitely long time - known as a *never-resolving*/*never-settling* promise or *forever-pending* promise. (see also [promise terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572))
The term *may* is used deliberately here, and does carry the [conventional meaning](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt).

There even exist promise implementations that offer a `Promise.never` primitive (e.g. in [creed](https://github.com/briancavalier/creed#never--promise-e-a)) to optimise the memory consumption for the case when you know that your promise won't settle.