# What happens if await never returns?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

In ECMAScript I am using CancelablePromise (https://github.com/alkemics/CancelablePromise) that basically is just a Promise with a `.cancel()` function. Whenever `.cancel()` is called, the callbacks provided to `.then()` and `.catch()` are not executed.

I wonder what happens if I await on a cancelled promise:

```
CancelablePromise promise = new CancelablePromise((resolve, reject) => resolve(1));
const promise2 = promise.then(x => x + 1);
promise.cancel();
console.log(await promise2);
```

So this code works as expected, nothing is printed on console. However, I wonder if this creates any hanging threads / references that cannot be collected by the GC or is this perfectly safe and valid to use?

Comment: I imagine there would be references that the GC can't `collect` as the GC wouldn't "know" what a cancellable Promise is - sorry I can only speculate, perhaps someone with knowledge of the internals of every javascript engine may stumble on this question and be able to give a definitive answer :p

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/34289551/1048572

Comment: Don't use that library. It's implemented horribly.

Comment: @Bergi, can you please be more specific?

Comment: About the implementation? I'd rather not. But yes, [*that* library](https://github.com/alkemics/CancelablePromise/blob/6be165b63d89b46d10e02428925fc4b1260d416c/CancelablePromise.js) does leak memory under a few circumstances.

Answer (score 10):

`await` is just syntactical sugar on top of promises.  It's analogous to a `p.then()` statement in ES6.  In ES6, if the promise never resolves, then the code inside the `.then()` handler never executes.  With `await`, the interpreter essential puts the following code block inside an automatically created `.then()` handler.  Internally, it pretty much works the same way.

There are no extra threads left running.  `await` doesn't use threads. Depending upon exactly why the promise never resolves, the promise itself likely never gets GCed because internally, there's probably still a reference to it by the underlying code that "could" resolve it at some point in the future.

While this isn't a disaster, it's probably not a good design.  If there's some condition where the promise may never resolve, then you should probably at least use a timeout and clear references to the promise or find a way to cancel the underlying operation.  Without specific details to what the operation actually is, we can't provide more specific recommendations.