# Using unresolved promise to make conditional filter/branching

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to filter and route promise based on its result, so I use code like this that uses unresolved promise to omit executing of a branch:

```
const resultP = getSomething()
  .then((result) => result === 'good' ? true : false )
    
const goodStuffP = resultP
  // procceds if r is true, otherwise returns unresolved promise (so that branch is omitted)
  .then((r) => r ? r : new Promise(() =>{})) 
  .then(...do good stuff...)

const badStuffP = resultP
 // procceds if r is false, otherwise returns unresolved promise
.then((r) => !r ? r : new Promise(() =>{}))
.then(...do bad stuff...)
```

I wonder if something wrong with this approach, that thing that doesn't look ok to me is an unresolved promise.

So is using unresolved promise this way is a valid use in terms of possible tech issues (like leaks)? The question is **not about** good/bad programming style.

Comment: Why not just use `if (r) { /* do good stuff */ } else { /* do bad stuff */ }`?

Comment: You should start off by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise

Comment: No, don't use unresolved promises for control flow. Just use `if`/`else`.

Comment: @Phil the question is about the validity of using unresolved promise, not how to get rid of it.

Comment: @Bergi why, what is the reason?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR It's horrible and overcomplicated

Comment: @Bergi this is subjective.

Comment: Does this work? Does it meet your requirements? If so then there's nothing "wrong" with it.

Comment: See my answer below I just asked the question before found the node's thread on never resolved promises.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't use unresolved promises for control flow. Just use `if`/`else` inside that `then` callback:

```
const resultP = getSomething().then(result => {
  if (result === 'good') {
    // ...do good stuff, return a value
  } else {
    // ...do bad stuff, return a value
  }
});
```

Comment: Why, this is the obvious option, I'm asking about why my option is not valid if so.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Because it is bad coding not to use the obvious, simple and working solution. The approach with unresolved promises has too many non-obvious edge cases (like bugs when it comes to dealing with rejections). Not sure what you mean by "valid", but there is simply no good reason to use it even if you fix the bugs.

Comment: I mean can it cause some tech issues like a leak or something.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Yes, it has those (I briefly mentioned one - hint: try rejecting `getSomething()`), but what makes the solution so horrible is that you cannot easily notice them.

Comment: What is the problem with rejecting? It will be handle in catch if needed, in both branches.

Comment: Found this issue btw https://github.com/nodejs/promises-debugging/issues/16 it states that not resolving a promise is actually a valid case.

Comment: @Whitecolor: yes, the problem is that you now need to do it in both branches. Which works subtly different than the normal straight-forward solution.

Comment: And yes, not resolving promises is valid (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34289551/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38286358/1048572)) and [is expected not to leak memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20068467/1048572) (although [some implementations don't live up to that](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=9858)). However, it is not a valid solution for the `if`/`else` branching problem.

Comment: Sometimes you want to avoid clumsy if/else (in general), the same for try/catch constructs.

Comment: @Whitecolor: "clumsy" is subjective, and in my opinion a never-resolving promise is a much more clumsy solution. But it seems we disagree there. Or maybe you've haven't presented your actual use case well.

Comment: Yeah, this clumsiness can be concealed if needed. This issue is to get FP oriented style.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer seems to be like this: using not ever resolved promises in the code is an absolutely valid case. It is like not calling the callback, which is not should be forced. Just catch and handle errors correctly.

Nodejs repo issue discussing not ever resolved promises in the code:
https://github.com/nodejs/promises-debugging/issues/16