# Why does this Promise in Parse Cloud Code not work?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

The following Cloud Code function on [Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) does not work as expected.

It seems to resolve too early so that not all chained promises of `promise2` are executed. In particular I see some of the `resultA.add(...);` not being executed.

I have tried to re-arrange this several times without success.

I am not sure if `return Parse.Promise.resolve();` is what I should return in the `else` clause or if it is something else or nothing.

Can anyone spot something here?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("aFunction", function(request, response) {

    var q = new Parse.Query("ClassA");    
    q.find()
    .then(
        function(resultsA) {

            var promise = new Parse.Promise.as();
            resultsA.forEach(function(resultA) {

                promise = promise
                .then(
                    function() {
                        var q = new Parse.Query("ClassB");
                        return q.first();
                    }
                )
                .then(
                    function(resultB) {

                        if (resultB != undefined) {
                            resultA.set(...);
                            return resultA.save();

                        } else {
                            resultA.set(...);
                            return resultA.save();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .then(
                    function() {

                        var q = new Parse.Query("ClassC");
                        return q.find()

                        .then(
                            function(resultsC) {
                                if (resultsC != undefined && resultsC.length > 0) {

                                    var promise2 = new Parse.Promise.as();
                                    resultsC.forEach(function(resultC) {
                                        promise2 = promise2
                                        .then(
                                            function() {
                                                resultA.add(...);
                                                return resultA.save();
                                            }
                                        );
                                    });
                                    return promise2;

                                } else {
                                    return Parse.Promise.resolve();
                                } 
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            });
            return promise;
        }
    )
    .then(
        function(result) {
            response.success("success");
        },
        function(error) {
            response.error(error.message);
        }
    );
});
```

Long code but I already stripped it down and wanted to show the actual structure. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `return undefined` or `return Promise.resolve(undefined)` (to the same effect) seem appropriate.

Comment: Oh wait, for the Parse API it's `return Parse.Promise.as(undefined)`, not `.resolve`

Comment: @Bergi The `.as` method seems to be used to predefine the return value of a resolved promise at the time of promise declaration. To actually resolve the promise it is still necessary to call `.resolve` on it. In other words `Parse.Promise.as(aValue); Parse.Promie.resolve();` is equivalent to `Parse.Promise.resolve(aValue);`.

Comment: Oh my, the Parse terminology is so confusing (it doesn't really comply with [any standards](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572)). I always have to double-check [the source](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/v1.8.5/src/ParsePromise.js) to be sure. Their `Promise.resolve(x)` and `Promise.as(x)` methods do mostly the same, except that `resolve` treats thenables as expected and `as` just fulfills with the value. In any case, they are exchangeable when used with `undefined` like in your case (and you better should only use one of them for consistency).

Answer (score 0):

just checked your code.
And i'm not sure if it's your type mistake , when you 'clean your code' for showing structure.

in your loop: chats.forEach(function(resultA) ..

It seems like you haven't declare 'chats' variable.

Also, as Parse official recommended , please try following:

```
var _ = require('underscore.js');

var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
_.each(resultsA, function(resultA) {

    promise = promise.then(function() {..}.then..then..
}
return promise;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, `chats` was a typo, code corrected. I am using `Parse.Promises` in other functions and they work fine. I think it is due to the structure of the nested promises that it doesn't work.