# How can a Promise be resolved and pending?

Tags: javascript, promise

The [spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-promise-objects):

> A resolved promise may be pending, fulfilled or rejected.

How can a Promise be resolved and pending?

Comment: [What is the correct terminology for javascript promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268569/what-is-the-correct-terminology-for-javascript-promises#answer-29269515)

Comment: resolved != fulfilled

Comment: OK thanks. I get it. Resolution also covers the binding of an outer promise' state to that of an inner. Hence The outer promise can be pending (on an inner promise), and resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right there in the section you linked to:

> A promise is *resolved* if it is settled or if it has been “locked in” to match the state of another promise. [...]

That other promises might still be pending. Lets take a look at an example:

```
var p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
var q = Promise.resolve(p);

// At this point `q` is resolved / "locked in"  but still pending
// because the `p` promise is also still pending.

// Only after the timeout has passed, the `p` promise will resolve/settle 
// and `q` will assume the inner promises state.
```

---

Looks like Bergi wrote a pretty comprehensive answer around promise terminology: [What is the correct terminology for javascript promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268569/what-is-the-correct-terminology-for-javascript-promises#answer-29269515)

Comment: hi @Felix Kling, there `p` at the beginning is unresolved because it doesn't know if `resolve()` or `reject()` is going to be called and because it is not associated to another promise either, right?

Comment: @Coder23: That's right.

Comment: Thank you @Felix Kling +1, I had doubts about the term *resolved*, but now I understand it.