# How does nesting of promises work in javascipt

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

why does it print promise pending?
I was expecting it might give promise<promise<1>> or promise<1>

```js
let k = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let a = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res(1);
  });
  resolve(a);
});

console.log(k); // run with browser console open
```

Comment: Because at that point in time it is pending.

Comment: @KevinB `res` and `resolve` are called before the `console.log`

Comment: @Konrad but resolving a promise with another promise is not immediate (unlike fulfilling it with a primitive value)

Comment: Apart from the answer to the duplicate, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964819/what-should-happen-if-you-resolve-a-promise-with-another-promise or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733021/is-promise-resolve-a-asynchronous-function

Comment: when i add console.log(a) above resolve(a) I get Promise{1}

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you wait until the promise has resolved

```
let k = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let a = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res("boink");
  });
  resolve(a)
});

k.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: For fun: Change `"boink"` to `"The Promise Lake froze over."` :)

Comment: I promise I will do that