# Is it necessary to wrap a promise in a function?

Tags: javascript, redux, promise

#### I have this situation :

```js
import processAsyncCall from "../helpers/processAsyncCall";

const promiseWrapper = () => new Promise((res, rej) => { /* [1] */ });
const onResolve = () => { /* [2] */ };

dispatch(processAsyncCall(promiseWrapper, onResolve));
```

1. The `promiseWrapper` contains a promise that will resolve when a certain action is made (ex: fetch a file, update content, etc.).
2. This method will be called when the `promise` inside the `promiseWrapper` has resolved.

---

Let's take a look at `processAsyncCall`.

```js
export default (
  promiseWrapper,
  onResolve = null,
) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(showLoading());
  promiseWrapper()
    .then(result => {
      if (onResolve !== null && typeof onResolve === "function") {
        onResolve(dispatch, getState)(result);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => console.log("ERROR_IN_ASYNC"))
    .finally(() => dispatch(hideLoading()));
  });
};
```

The important part is `promiseWrapper().then(result => { /* ... */})`.

I execute the function `promiseWrapper` to create the **Promise** *on the spot*.

---

#### My question :

> Is it necessary to wrap a promise in a function to ensure that it is not **resolved** before it is processed?

I had this problem where the `then` callback wouldn't work if I passed my **Promise** directly as a parameter.

```js
dispatch(processAsyncCall(new Promise(/* ... */), /* ... */));
```

My understanding is that when a **promise resolves**, the `then` callback is called. But if the function resolves and there is no `then` callback at that time, the **Promise** is *done/completed/dead*.

Keep in mind that the example above is pretty straightforward, but in some cases the **Promise** is created elsewhere and it is passed down until it reaches the `processAsyncCall` function.

Comment: "*I execute the function `promiseWrapper` to create the Promise on the spot.*" - don't you want to do the action that creates the promise *after* `dispatch(showLoading())`?

Comment: "*if the function resolves and there is no then callback at that time, the Promise is dead*" - nope, not at all. Promises don't die. They enter the resolved state when you resolve them. You can install any amount of `then` callbacks to them, they *always* get called when the promise is fulfilled - even when the promise had been resolved *before* the `then` call.

Comment: @Bergi It is a good suggestion! In my case I don't mind in the loading is not exacly before the action. I thought of chaining them `dispatch(showLoading()).then(/* ... */)`. I can still improve it later :)

Comment: The reason you'd wrap the promise like this is so you can choose when the code should begin executing, rather than having it execute immediately after define-time. Also, consider rewriting this using `async`/`await`, I think you'll see it becomes a lot easier to read

Comment: @PaulS. This is absolutely right : "The reason you'd wrap the promise like this is so you can choose when the code should begin executing". I wrote this code 3 months ago and so I forgot why I needed it to **resolve** in `processAsyncCall`. I will consider rewriting with the `async/await` later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that Promise behaviour remains a little mysterious in your mind.

You can imagine a Promise as an object having 4 properties :

- a state,
- a value,
- a list of callback that will be called in case of success,
- a list of callback to be called if it failed.

The `state` always start at `pending`, and the code inside your promise is stacked to be called in the next execution loop as if you had called it with `setImmediate`.

The promise can only resolve or reject once and will remain in that state forever after that.

When a promise is resolved/rejected, its state changes to `fulfilled` or `rejected`, and the corresponding callbacks are called in order.

When you call `then` or `catch` on a Promise, if the state of the Promise is `pending`, the callback is added to the corresponding list. If the promise is already resolved (respectively rejected), the callback will be called in the next execution loop.

I hope it can help you understand what happens here.

Comment: Nitpick: [the states are a bit more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572) regarding `resolve`, and "*If the promise is already fulfilled, the callback is immediately called.*" should be "…is immediately scheduled" (not called - it's still asynchronous).

Comment: Try this: `a = Promise.resolve();` and later: `a.then(console.log('1'));
console.log("2");`. If the promise is resolved it is not asynchronous. But you're right about the states. I really simplified.

Comment: That's because you need to use `a.then(() => { console.log('1'); })`

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation! I understood alright with @deceze's answer, but your answer is more about the *WHY* is the `then` callback called each time. I understand that the answer is not exact, but it is enough for me to understand the mecanism behind! I will try to code a **Promise** object this week and see how it can be done :)

Comment: @Bergi OMG! You're right. I was not sure so I made this quick check but I did it too quickly apparently...

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that when a promise resolves, the then callback is called. But if the function resolves and there is no then callback at that time, the Promise is done/completed/dead.

That is incorrect. By definition, code cannot know *when* a promise will resolve, and requiring code to attach a callback *before* it resolves would put considerable constraints on promises and make them much less useful. No, you can attach a new callback at any time and it will be called:

```js
const p = new Promise(r => {
    r('yay');
    setTimeout(() => p.then(console.log));
});

p.then(console.log);
```

The difference in *your* case is probably simply whether `processAsyncCall` expects a promise as argument or a function that returns a promise. Those are different types and must be handled differently, obviously.