# When is an ES6 promise fulfillment handler table examined?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, job-queue

Is it true that the `resolve()` function and `then()` function below are the only functions in the ES6 Promise mechanism that look at and add the fulfillment handlers to the job queue (and mark them as already added and never again)?

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("resolve, reject are", resolve, reject);
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("this is the success data");
    }, 1000);
});

promise.then(
  function(a) { 
    console.log("Success.", a); 
    promise.then(function(a) { console.log("Go have a drink.", a); });
  },
  function(a) { 
    console.log("failure", a) 
  }
);
```

An alternative to the above code is, the `resolve()` is done directly, without being in the `setTimeout()`.  Is it true that the `then(fn)` will add the `fn` to the fulfillment handler table (not job queue) for this promise, or if the promise has already been resolved, directly add the `fn` to the job queue, and the `fn` is marked as "already added to job queue" and no need to be added again?

On the other hand, the `resolve()` is a JS ES6 provided function, that mark a promise as "resolved" (state), and check if the fulfillment handler table for this promise is empty or not. If there are such handlers (and should not have been marked already added to the job queue before), then these handlers are added to the job queue and marked as already added.

And in any event, suppose there are `fn1`, `fn2`, `fn3`, ... etc in the fulfillment handler table, each one is added to the job queue as `fn1(resolvedValue)`, where the `resolvedValue` is remembered internally by the `resolve(resolveValue)` call?

And there are no other situation where the fulfillment handler table is accessed at all. The job queue jobs are executed by the JS event loop, so that when all the GUI "click event handlers", etc are done, then the fulfillment (and rejection) handlers in the job queue are executed, and then also the setTimeout and setInterval handlers are also executed?  Is this how the fulfillment handler table and job queue work?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that the `resolve()` function and `then()` function below are the only functions in the ES6 Promise mechanism that look at and add the fulfillment handlers to the job queue?

Yes. (`reject` also looks at the table and removes handlers without adding them to the job queue).

> Is it true that the `then(fn)` will add the `fn` to the fulfillment handler table (not job queue) for this promise, or if the promise has already been resolved, directly add the `fn` to the job queue?

Yes.

> and the `fn` is marked as "already added to job queue" and no need to be added again?

No, the `fn` is not marked at all. It could be passed multiple times to `then`, in which case it would need to be run multiple times.
But yes, the fulfillment handler table is cleared when the promise fulfills and the callback jobs are scheduled.

> And in any event, suppose there are `fn1`, `fn2`, `fn3`, ... etc in the fulfillment handler table, each one is added to the job queue as `fn1(resolvedValue)`, where the `resolvedValue` is remembered internally by the `resolve(resolveValue)` call?

Yes. Although technically [`resolve` does not always fulfill the promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572).

> And there are no other situation where the fulfillment handler table is accessed at all.

Yes. I wonder why you care though.

> The job queue jobs are executed by the JS event loop, so that when all the GUI "click event handlers", etc are done, then the fulfillment (and rejection) handlers in the job queue are executed, and then also the setTimeout and setInterval handlers are also executed?  Is this how the fulfillment handler table and job queue work?

Yes. However notice that [click handlers, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` have a separate event queue from promise jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25915634/1048572).

Comment: Q: "And there are no other situation where the fulfillment handler table is accessed at all." A: "Yes. I wonder why you care though."  The reason is, before, I thought there might be some system loop that constantly look at the promise handlers and decide whether to run them. And then later on, it appears there is no such loop as the precise moment where these handlers can be executed (or added to a job queue to be executed) is known: either at the `resolve()` moment or the `then()` moment

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, there is no part of the event loop that tracks all individual promises, that would be pretty inefficient. There might be optimisations applied where handlers are not "moved" from the fulfillment handler table to the job queue and instead just a reference being created (so that the table becomes "part of" the queue), but those shouldn't change the conceptual model.