# What is the difference between Promise.any() and Promise.race()

Tags: javascript, promise

What is the difference between `Promise.any()` and `Promise.race()`, and how do they get used differently?

---

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any),

> Also, unlike Promise.race(), which returns the first settled value,
> this method returns the first resolved value. This method will ignore
> all rejected promises up until the first promise that resolves.

So that brings me to, the difference between **resolved** and **settled**. Which then brought me to the MDN promises [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which **then** brought me to [States and Fates](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/docs/states-and-fates.md)

> Being settled is not a state, just a linguistic convenience.

So we have `Promise.any` and `Promise.race` for linguistic convenience? i.e. there **is no** difference. Another instance of this equality, is "A promise whose fate is unresolved is necessarily pending." and "We say that a promise is settled if it is not pending, i.e. if it is either fulfilled or rejected.".

So if a promise is resolved, it is not unresolved, so it is not pending. So then, if it's not pending, it's settled. So resolved === settled.

Comment: Settled means done, resolved means done **successfully**

Comment: settled = resolved or rejected. resolved = not rejected

Comment: "*So resolved === settled*"  it's not full equality. `dog = animal` is true but `anima = dog` is false. Settled is a super category.

Comment: Okay I think i understand it now, should I delete this question

Comment: Oh wait, no. According to 'States and Fates', "A promise whose fate is resolved can be in any of the three states: fulfilled, rejected or pending".

Comment: i think comments above are confusing resolved with fulfilled.

Comment: @apokryfos - No, "resolved" means that the promise either *is* settled or *will be* settled by the result of another promise. A resolved promise can still be pending. The *states* are pending, fulfilled, or rejected.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there's no practical way to get a resolved promise that's still pending though since the resolved value is chained

Comment: @apokryfos - I don't know what you mean by that. There's definitely a substantial difference between a *resolved* promise and a *fulfilled* one, and you can easily observe that a promise is pending (hook fulfillment and rejection and wait a tick -- if you didn't get a callback, the promise was pending during that time).

Comment: @BenB I've fixed the MDN page with [proper terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572)

Comment: @apokryfos `Promise.resolve({then(){}})` is the shortest example of a resolved but pending promise. In general, you can resolve a promise with another promise, which means you cannot resolve it again, but when that other promise is still pending then so is yours.

Comment: @Bergi my point is `Promise.any` or `Promise.race` will not return until the entire chain is settled or resolved so there's no practical way to get a result from either of these functions that's still pending, as far as I know

Comment: @apokryfos of course the promise that `Promise.any` does return is pending until the condition for settling it is met. (And before further confusion occurs, my comment to you did respond to "*there's no practical way to get a resolved promise that's still pending*")

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`Promise.race` and `Promise.any` do different things:

`Promise.race` is settled as soon as any of the promises you feed it settle, whether they are fulfilled or rejected.

`Promise.any` is settled as soon as any of the promises you feed it *is fulfilled* or they are **all** rejected, in which case it's rejected with an `AggregateError`.

The chief differences are:

1. `race`'s promise is rejected when the first promise you give it is rejected; `any`'s promise isn't, because another promise may be fulfilled instead.
2. `any`'s promise's rejection reason will be an `AggregateError`, but `race`'s rejection reason will be the rejection reason from the first promise that was rejected.

So if you pass them both an array of two promises, and one of the promises is rejected, then afterward the other promise is fulfilled, the promise from `Promise.race` will be rejected (because the first promise to settle was rejected) and the promise from `Promise.any` will be fulfilled (because although the first promise was rejected, the second was fulfilled). E.g.:

```js
const a = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject,  100, new Error("a")));
const b = new Promise((resolve)   => setTimeout(resolve, 200, "b"));

Promise.race([a, b]).then(
    value => {
        console.log(`race: fulfilled with ${value}`);
    },
    reason => {
        console.log(`race: rejected with ${reason.message}`);
    }
);

Promise.any([a, b]).then(
    value => {
        console.log(`any:  fulfilled with ${value}`);
    },
    reason => {
        console.log(`any:  rejected with ${reason.errors.map(({message}) => message).join()}`);
    }
);
```

With a JavaScript engine that has `Promise.any` (or a polyfill), that outputs

```
race: rejected with a
any:  fulfilled with b
```

Play with various outcomes here (there's a *very* rough incomplete stand-in for `Promise.any` included if your browser doesn't have it yet):

```js
addFakeAnyIfMissing();

document.querySelector("input[value='Start Again']").addEventListener("click", run);

run();

function setupPromise(name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const div = document.querySelector(`[data-for="${name}"]`);
        const btnFulfill = div.querySelector("input[value=Fulfill]");
        const btnReject  = div.querySelector("input[value=Reject]");;
        const display    = div.querySelector(".display");
        btnFulfill.disabled = btnReject.disabled = false;
        display.textContent = "pending";
        btnFulfill.onclick = () => {
            resolve(name);
            display.textContent = `fulfilled with ${name}`;
            btnFulfill.disabled = btnReject.disabled = true;
        };
        btnReject.onclick = () => {
            reject(new Error(name));
            display.textContent = `rejected with Error(${name})`;
            btnFulfill.disabled = btnReject.disabled = true;
        };
    });
}

function run() {
    const a = setupPromise("a");
    const b = setupPromise("b");
    const raceDisplay = document.querySelector("[data-for=race] .display");
    const anyDisplay  = document.querySelector("[data-for=any]  .display");
    raceDisplay.textContent = anyDisplay.textContent = "pending";

    Promise.race([a, b]).then(
        value => {
            raceDisplay.textContent = `fulfilled with ${value}`;
        },
        reason => {
            raceDisplay.textContent = `rejected with ${reason.message}`;
        }
    );

    Promise.any([a, b]).then(
        value => {
            anyDisplay.textContent = `fulfilled with ${value}`;
        },
        reason => {
            anyDisplay.textContent = `rejected with ${reason.errors.map(({message}) => message).join()}`;
        }
    );
}

function addFakeAnyIfMissing() {
    if (!Promise.any) {
        // VERY ROUGH STANDIN, not a valid polyfill
        class AggregateError extends Error {}
        Object.defineProperty(Promise, "any", {
            value(iterable) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const errors = [];
                    let waitingFor = 0;
                    for (const value of iterable) {
                        const index = waitingFor++;
                        Promise.resolve(value).then(
                            value => {
                                resolve(value);
                                --waitingFor;
                            },
                            reason => {
                                errors[index] = reason;
                                if (--waitingFor === 0) {
                                    reject(Object.assign(new AggregateError(), {errors}));
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
            },
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div data-for="a">
    Promise A
    <input type="button" value="Fulfill">
    <input type="button" value="Reject">
    <span class="display"></span>
</div>
<div data-for="b">
    Promise B
    <input type="button" value="Fulfill">
    <input type="button" value="Reject">
    <span class="display"></span>
</div>
<div data-for="race">
    <code>Promise.race([a, b])</code>:
    <span class="display"></span>
</div>
<div data-for="any">
    <code>Promise.any([a, b])</code>:
    <span class="display"></span>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Start Again">
```

This chart from [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-any) may help:

> There are [four main combinators in the Promise landscape](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators).
>
> ```
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | name               | description                                     |                 |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Promise.allSettled | does not short-circuit                          | Added in ES2020 |
> | Promise.all        | short-circuits when an input value is rejected  | Added in ES2015 |
> | Promise.race       | short-circuits when an input value is settled   | Added in ES2015 |
> | Promise.any        | short-circuits when an input value is fulfilled | this proposal   |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> ```

Continuing with your question...

> Another instance of this equality, is "A promise whose fate is unresolved is necessarily pending." and "We say that a promise is settled if it is not pending, i.e. if it is either fulfilled or rejected.".
>
> So if a promise is resolved, it is not unresolved, so it is not pending. So then, if its not pending, its settled. So resolved === settled.

I can see how you got there, but you can't invert it like that. :-) A resolved promise can be pending. It's just that an *unresolved* promise is *definitely* pending.

The states are:

- pending
- fulfilled
- rejected

You can resolve a promise (`A`) to another promise (`B`), which means that while `A` may still be pending, nothing can change what's going to happen to it; its fate is sealed, it will be fulfilled or rejected according to what happens to `B`.

(More about this in my blog post [*Let's talk about how to talk about promises*](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).)

Here's an example of a pending resolved promise:

```js
const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            resolve("all good");
        } else {
            reject(new Error("ugh"));
        }
    }, 100);
});

// (Being verbose for clarity)
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(b);
    // Now, `a` is pending, but resolved
    // No matter what else we do, `a`'s fate is tied to
    // `b`'s. For instance, this does nothing:
    resolve("foo");
    // Neither does this:
    reject(new Error("foo"));
});

b
.then(value => {
    console.log(`b was fulfilled: ${value}`);
})
.catch(reason => {
    console.log(`b was rejected: ${reason.message}`);
});

a
.then(value => {
    console.log(`a was fulfilled: ${value}`);
})
.catch(reason => {
    console.log(`a was rejected: ${reason.message}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the code examples. I suspect this answer will prove useful to coders for years to come!

Comment: hi @T.J. Crowder excellent+1, there `b` at the beginning is unresolved because it doesn't know if `resolve()` or `reject()` is going to be called and because it is not associated to another promise either, right?

Comment: Speaking of the last code example in your answer @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - Nearly: It's unresolved because its fate isn't tied to another promise. Even if we knew it was going to be fulfilled (for instance, the standard [sleep promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/157247)), I don't think we'd say it was *resolved*, per se. But I see your point that it's similar.