# What are the differences between Promise.all() and Promise.any() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

When working with the `Promise` object in JavaScript, I noticed two methods, which were `Promise.all()` and `Promise.any()`.

Both of them take an iterable (such as an `array`) as a parameter. However, I can't find what each method does differently.

After searching it on *MDN*, it was still hard to find a summary for the differences between the two methods.

In conclusion, what are the differences between `Promise.all()` and `Promise.any()` in JavaScript?

---

***Note:** This question is not related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732049/what-is-the-difference-between-promise-any-and-promise-race#:%7E:text=do%20different%20things%3A-,Promise.,it%27s%20rejected%20with%20an%20AggregateError%20.). Instead of `Promise.race()`, I am asking about `Promise.all()`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` only resolves when all `Promise`s in the array passed in are resolved, and returns the array of resolved `Promise`s. If any `Promise` inside the iterator rejects, `Promise.all` rejects (I assume with the reason of the original rejection).

`Promise.any` resolves when any `Promise` in the array passed in, and returns the first `Promise` to do so. It doesn't reject unless all `Promise`s in the iterator are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all - resolve all promises passed as an iterable object. It also rejects completely when an input value is rejected since it follows an **all-or-nothing methodology**.

Promise.any - takes an iterable of Promise objects and, as soon as one of the promises in the iterable fulfills,it returns a single promise that resolves with the value from that promise.