# What if we try to resolve one pending promise in another promise

Tags: javascript, promise

In this I have a doubt that res(p2) only gets resolved once p2 promise gets settled so how this mechanism works how do res know that p2 is pending.

```js
function run(p2) {
  let p1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log(p2)
    res(p2)
  })
  p1.then(val => console.log(val))
}
let p2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res('po')
  }, 6000)
})
run(p2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit simplified example, showing how this works exactly:

```js
const base = new Promise((resolveFunc) => {

  resolveFunc(new Promise((innerResolveFunc) => {
    setTimeout(() => innerResolveFunc(), 2000);
  }))

});

base.then(() => console.log('resolved'))
```

The `base` promise will be fulfilled, when the promise passed as an argument of `resolveFunc` is fulfilled. In this example, `console.log` will run after 2 seconds.

Here is an explanation from MDN:

> The value parameter passed to resolveFunc can be another promise object, in which case the newly constructed promise's state will be "locked in" to the promise passed (as part of the resolution promise).

Comment: Thanks , thats answer my doubt the base promise gets locked till the promise passed is resolved

Answer (score 1):

`p1` is created and immediately resolved with the promise `p2`. Meaning that p1 transitions from the pending state to the fulfilled state, and its resolution value becomes p2.

The .then() handler attached to `p1` logs the value of p1, which is the `p2` promise object itself.

Promises are a way to work with asynchronous code in a more structured and manageable manner, allowing you to handle the results of asynchronous operations more elegantly and avoid callback hell. As a result you don't need a timer in your code.

Comment: This is incorrect. `p1` is not immediately fulfilled (otherwise it would immediately schedule the `console.log(val)` callback), and it is not fulfilled with `p2` either. It is [**resolved** immediately with `p2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572), and fulfills only when `p2` fulfills.