# Why promise state shows pending, when it has resolved to another promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, jobs, asynccallback

Below code snippet I have taken from the famous YDKJS - Async & Performance series, and have made a few changes for the sake of understanding.

```
var p3 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    resolve( "B" );
} );
var p1 = new Promise( function(res,rej){
  resolve( p3 ); // equivalent to p3.then(res)
} );
var p2 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    resolve( "A" );
} );
p1.then( function(v){
    console.log("In p1");
    console.log(p1);
} );
p2.then( function(v){
    console.log("In p2");
    console.log(p1);
} );
```

Although the order in which the results are logged are as per desire, but the state of promise p1 shows pending (at `console.log(p1)`) which I could not understand. I have tried to depict through pictures (at the end) what I have understood so far, so you can correct me where I'm wrong.

**Result**

[image]

At **Stage 1**: `p1` resolves to an already resolved promise, `p3`. I know `p1` would still remain pending and would not resolve to a value yet. But I have heard that `resolve(p3)` is equivalent to

```
p3.then(res);  // res is a resolve callback of p1
```

So based on this assumption, since `p3` is both resolved and has a registered handler (callback `res` of `p1`) it will be inserted into Micro Task Queue (MTQ).

At **Stage 2**: `p2` is both resolved and has a registered handler (in purple) it will be appended to MTQ.

At **Stage 3**: Now as there's left nothing on stack to execute, the cb (in yellow) which was first inserted in MTQ will get on stack for execution.
Here are my Queries: When `res('B')` executes will it mark the `p1`'s state as Fulfilled? Since res is the callback associated with `p1`.

As `p1` already has a registered handler (when `p1.then` was called) besides being fulfilled, wouldn't it append to the MTQ as depicted at **Stage 4**?

If so, then why is `p1` still showing as pending even at **Stage 5**?

And at **Stage 6**: How does `p1` gets fulfilled all of a sudden?

Please assist me to understand where I'm wrong in below pictorial depiction?

[image]

Comment: *”Although the order in which the results are logged are as per desire”* — Err, no, they’re in opposite order…!? Which is also the answer to the mystery.

Comment: @deceze Yes the opposite order is the predictable one. But why is p1 pending is not clear

Comment: Just to help get rid of some of the complexity to make it a bit easier to grok, you can replace `resolve(p3)` with `resolve(Promise.resolve('B')` and observe the same behaviour

Comment: While p3 is resolved at stage 3, p1's resolution (or rejection) results from (as you pointed out) the execution of `p3.then`. So when `p3` get's resolved, `p3.then`'s execution gets added to the queue to be executed when nothing else is running

Comment: @AdamJenkins Exactly! Then why p1 is showing Pending, as per logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why promise state shows *pending*, when it has resolved to another promise?

That's just [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572). The implementation  does not distinguish between the "unresolved" and "resolved" pending states.

> When `res('B')` executes will it mark the `p1`'s state as Fulfilled?

Yes.

> Wouldn't the callback registered on `p1` be appended to the MTQ as depicted at Stage 4? Why is `p1` still showing as pending even at Stage 5?

Your reasoning is mostly correct. Yes, it would. In fact, if you had written `p3.then(resolve)` in your `p1` execution callback, that's exactly what would have happened and the Stage 5 `console.log` would have printed *Promise {<fulfilled>: 'B'}*.

> I have heard that `resolve(p3)` is equivalent to `p3.then(resolve);`. So based on this assumption…

That assumption is not exactly valid. It is indeed mostly equivalent in behaviour, but it is not equivalent in microtask timing. When you pass a thenable (a promise) to `resolve`, it will actually schedule the call to the `.then(resolve, reject)` in a new microtask instead of synchronously calling it from within `resolve()`.

1. - a: `p3` is created, `p3` is fulfilled with `"B"`
   - b: `p1` is created, `resolve(p3)` accesses `p3.then`, finds it to be a method, and schedules a callback to invoke it
   - c: `p2` is created, `p2` is fulfilled with `"A"`
   - d: `p1.then(…)` registers a callback on the promise
   - e: `p2.then(…)` sees that `p2` is already fulfilled and schedules the callback
2. The task from step 1b runs and calls `p3.then(resolve, reject)` to adopt its state to `p1`. It sees that `p3` is already fulfilled and schedules the callback
3. The task from step 1e runs:

   - a: it logs `"In p2"`
   - b: it logs `p1`, which is still pending (but already resolved to `p3`)
4. The task from step 2 runs and calls `resolve("B")`. This fulfills `p1` and schedules the callback that was registered on it.
5. The task from step 4 runs:

   - a: it logs `"In p1"`
   - b: it logs `p1`, which had been fulfilled with `"B"` in step 4.

You could read the spec for such intricate details, but really you just shouldn't rely on them (and they are changing from time to time - in fact the very detail that you missed is [proposed to change](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-faster-promise-adoption)). You have two independent promise chains, and you should not make any assumptions on the order of callbacks between `p1` and `p2`. If it was important, you'd make the promises dependent on each other.

Comment: "When you pass a thenable (a promise) to resolve, it will actually schedule the call to the .then(resolve, reject) in a new microtask instead of synchronously calling it from within resolve()" - You are referring to what I have pictorially depicted right!

Comment: @Sadiq You have pictorially depicted (rather well) what you also described in the text. Yes, that's what I was referring to. Your "stage 1" is wrong - `resolve(p3)` is not scheduling `() => resolve("B")`, it is scheduling `() => p3.then(resolve, reject)`. So in "stage 3" it does not already fulfill the promise, it is executing the `then` method which schedules `() => resolve("B")`.